# How to pull information from NSDictionary Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, nsdictionary

Right now I have a mapview that populates a bunch of pins based on a category, for example, 'Asian Food'. WHen i click the callout accessory of that annotation, the app navigates to a detail viewcontroller, which I hope to display the address and other properties. I am getting the information from the Yelp API CLient. Here is my model:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
var resultQueryDictionary:NSDictionary!

class Resturant: NSObject {
    var name: String!
    var thumbUrl: String!
    var address: String!
    var jsonData: NSData!
    var location: NSDictionary        // location


    init(dictionary: NSDictionary) {
        name = dictionary["name"] as? String
        thumbUrl = dictionary["thumbUrl"] as? String
        address = dictionary["address"] as? String
        self.location = dictionary["location"] as? NSDictionary ?? [:]
    }

    class func searchWithQuery(map: MKMapView, query: String, completion: ([Resturant]!, NSError!) -> Void) {
        YelpClient.sharedInstance.searchWithTerm(query,sort: 0, radius: 1069, success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, response: AnyObject!) -> Void in
            let responseInfo = response as! NSDictionary
            resultQueryDictionary = responseInfo
            println(responseInfo)
            let dataArray = responseInfo["businesses"] as! NSArray
            for business in dataArray {
                let obj = business as! NSDictionary
                var yelpBusinessMock: YelpBusiness = YelpBusiness(dictionary: obj)
                var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = yelpBusinessMock.location.coordinate
                annotation.title = yelpBusinessMock.name
                annotation.subtitle = yelpBusinessMock.displayAddress
                attractionDetailAddressString = yelpBusinessMock.displayAddress
                map.addAnnotation(annotation)
            }
            }) { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
         println(error)
        }
    }
    // term: String, deal: Bool, radius: Int, sort: Int, categories: String, success: (AFHTTPRequestOperation!, AnyObject!) -> Void, failure: (AFHTTPRequestOperation!, NSError!) -> Void) -> AFHTTPRequestOperation! {

    class func searchWithQueryWithRadius(map: MKMapView, term: String, deal: Bool, radius: Int, sort: Int, categories: String, completion: ([Resturant]!, NSError!) -> Void) {
        YelpClient.sharedInstance.searchWithTerm(term, deal: false, radius: radius, sort: sort,categories: categories, success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, response: AnyObject!) -> Void in
            let responseInfo = response as! NSDictionary
            resultQueryDictionary = responseInfo
            println(responseInfo)
            let dataArray = responseInfo["businesses"] as! NSArray
            for business in dataArray {
                let obj = business as! NSDictionary
                var yelpBusinessMock: YelpBusiness = YelpBusiness(dictionary: obj)
                var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = yelpBusinessMock.location.coordinate
                annotation.title = yelpBusinessMock.name
                map.addAnnotation(annotation)
            }
            }) { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            println(error)
        }
    }

}
```

In my Attractions ViewController (where the user taps categories to populate the map with pins), I have this code for when the callout accessory is tapped:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView!, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl!) {
        if (control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView) {
            let selectedLocation = view.annotation;
            let selectedCoordinate = view.annotation.coordinate;
            var latitude = selectedCoordinate.latitude
            var longitude = selectedCoordinate.longitude
            var location:CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
            let businessPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: selectedCoordinate, addressDictionary: nil)
            indicatedMapItem = selectedCoordinate;
            let resturantMock:Resturant = Resturant(dictionary: resultQueryDictionary)
            attractionDict = resturantMock.location;
            performSegueWithIdentifier("attractionToDetail", sender: self);
        }
    }
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var attractionsDetailViewController:AttractionsDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AttractionsDetailViewController
        attractionsDetailViewController.attractionLocation = indicatedMapItem;
        attractionsDetailViewController.attractionLocationDetail = self.attractionDict
    }
```

In my Detail View Controller, I attempt to get the data for the specific business that is tapped.

```
func getYelpData() {
        var businessMock:Resturant = Resturant(dictionary: resultQueryDictionary)
        var address:NSDictionary = attractionLocationDetail //dictionary
        attractionDetailAddressString = businessMock.location["display_address"] as? String;
        self.addressLabel.text = attractionDetailAddressString
}
```

However, this displays that address is nil.

Basically I want to know how to get one instance of the business from the large NSDictionary of Businesses and then retrieve the data for that individual business in my detail VC.

This is my Github repo if you want to look at all the code:
https://github.com/ssharif6/Park-N-Go

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though your problem may be here on this line

```
attractionDict = resturantMock.location;
```

Your dictionary will have a location key, but *doesn't* have the keys as suggested here on that location sub dictionary:

```
init(dictionary: NSDictionary) {
    name = dictionary["name"] as? String
    thumbUrl = dictionary["thumbUrl"] as? String
    address = dictionary["address"] as? String
    self.location = dictionary["location"] as? NSDictionary ?? [:]
}
```

So naturally all those values will be `nil` when your VC gets loaded.
Those keys however do exist on the `resturantMock.business` dictionary - is that what you meant to write? :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the `resturantMock.business` dictionary, I don't have that?